# A/B Test from two distributions with unknown means

Tags: hypothesis-testing, python, t-distribution

I will run a experiment to check if a given change, represent some significance in user interactions. I have two sets, sampled from two groups, one called `control` which counts the number of interactions from 30 sampled users in control group, and I have `treatment` which counts the number of interactions from 30 sampled users with a test feature. They are given in the Python code below

```
import numpy as np

control   = np.array([1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2])
treatment = np.array([0, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 4])
```

For this test i will use the following parameters

Practical Significant Boundary: $d_{min} = 0.05$

Significance level $\alpha = 0.05$

```py
d_min = 0.05
alpha = 0.05
```

I want to check if **in average** there is no usage difference between the two groups. Then I state the  **null hypothesis** as

$H_0: \mu_t == \mu_c \implies d = 0$

where $\mu$ is the average of control group (c) or treatment group (t) and $d$ the difference $d = \mu_t - \mu_c$.

```py
mu_c = control.mean()
mu_t = treatment.mean()
d = mu_t - mu_c
```

By the characteristics of the data, I will use the **t-test** for evaluation. I will assume the variance is the same between both groups, that will give me the following computation to test statistics.

```
n_c = len(control) # Number of samples in control
n_t = len(treatment) # Number of samples in treatment

df = n_c - 1 + n_t - 1 # Degree of freedom

# squared sum of errors from control group
SS_c = np.sum((control - mu_c)**2)

# squared sum of errors from treatment group
SS_t = np.sum((treatment - mu_t)**2)

# Pooled standard error
S_pool = np.sqrt((SS_c + SS_t)/df)

# Test statistics for t-distribution
TS = d / (S_pool * np.sqrt(1/n_c + 1/n_t))
```

Now I will verify if the test confirms or rejects the null hypothesis. For that I compute the `t_alpha` with 58 degrees of freedom,

```py
import scipy.stats as stats

t_alpha = stats.t.ppf(1-alpha/2, df)

TS > t_alpha or TS < -t_alpha 
# Returns true
```

Since `TS` is out of the boundaries of `t_alpha` we can **reject the null hypothesis**.

Now I will verify if the result is practically significant, that is if my confidence interval including the standard error intersects somehow the significance region. For that I need to estimate the **margin error** ($m$), then compute the **confidence interval** from $d \pm m$

```
m = t_alpha * S_pool
ci = np.array([d - m, d + m])
```

Just for reminder `d` is the difference between the averages from two groups (control and treatment).

To visualize we can build the given plot.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 3))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.vlines(0, -1, 1)
ax.vlines([-d_min, d_min], -1, 1, linestyles='dashed', label="Significant boundary");
ax.plot(d, 0,'b.', label="Center Confidence Interval");
ax.hlines(0, *ci, 'b', label="Confidence Interval");
ax.set_title("Significance");
plt.legend();
```

[image: Significance]

Since the confidence interval overlaps with the significant boundary (totally), even cross the $0$, I cannot assume that this test has practical significance, hence I would **reject** it.

**The problem is**: I was not expecting an interval SO large. Probably I just have used a wrong formula for margin error, but it seems correct. Any help to go forward in this is welcome.

Comment: Why do you think it is wrong? It seems reasonable. You have very few observations. Try just using an online calculator to verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's always a good idea to use existing implementations to check, especially for something as common as a t-test.

```py
import statsmodels.stats.weightstats as sm
test = sm.CompareMeans(sm.DescrStatsW(treatment), sm.DescrStatsW(control))
test.ttest_ind()
>>> TtestResult(statistic=1.0934, pvalue=0.2788, df=58.0)

test.tconfint_diff()
>>> (-0.2492, 0.8492)
```

Note that both contradict the results you have obtained. A statistical language like [`R`](https://www.r-project.org/) will confirm this and give you everything you want to know in a single line of code:

```r
t.test(treatment, control, var.equal = TRUE)
>   Two Sample t-test
> t = 1.0934, df = 58, p-value = 0.2788
> 95 percent confidence interval:
>  -0.2492  0.8492
```

Clearly you have at least one mistake in your formulae. I'm not sure why you end up with `TS` outside of the critical values because for me this is not the case when re-running your code:

```
TS = d / (S_pool * np.sqrt(1/n_c + 1/n_t))  # 1.0934
t_alpha = stats.t.ppf(1-alpha/2, df)        # 2.0017
TS > t_alpha or TS < -t_alpha
>>> False
```

The problem in your confidence interval calculation is that what you've called "pooled standard error" is actually the pooled standard **deviation**. The standard error is this quantity scaled by the square root of $n$ and also the denominator of your t statistic: `S_pool * np.sqrt(1/n_c + 1/n_t)`. Using that you'll end up with the correct CI:

```py
SE_pool = S_pool * np.sqrt(1/n_c + 1/n_t)
m = t_alpha * SE_pool
ci = np.array([d - m, d + m])
>>> array([-0.2492,  0.8492])
```

Finally, it's not clear what you mean by 'practical significance boundary'. The most liberal interpretation (and how you started your implementation) is that you want to test $H_0: \mu_t-\mu_c = 0$ and if you observe `d > d_min` you conclude that the effect might be practically relevant - if it were statistically significant. A more stringent interpretation, where you seem to want to go with your confidence interval, is that you actually want to test $H_0: \mu_t-\mu_c\le d_{min}$ which is the same as a $1-\alpha$ interval excluding `d_min`. I don't know which of these two you actually want, just highlighting that they are not the same. Neither of the null hypotheses can be rejected at the specified $\alpha$ in your case.

Comment: Indeed. I made a small mistake while transcribing the data from my local file to the SO. And here, at StackOverflow, with the "wrong" data, the **test statistics** confirms the null hypothesis. Good point is that using both Python Libs and R the test statistics values (the TS variable), are the same. it means that equation is correct. And indeed, my misnaming took me to a conceptual error, thank you for catching this up. With that fix (as you shown) the results are now equal than R and Python Stats. BTW, is there a name for this $np.sqrt(1/n_c + 1/n_t)$? It looks like a kind of harmonic mean.

Comment: If you keep the variances (which you already pooled in `S_pool`) in the denominators they are a weighted [pooled variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pooled_variance#Definition_and_computation). It's usually this variance that you divide by $n$ (or $n-1$) and the standard error by the degrees of freedom and not the other way around - the end result is the same regardless of order though.